# C# Как правильно реализовать модель?

Tags: c#, ооп

**ВВЕДЕНИЕ**

У меня есть класс `Module`. Он состоит, по-сути, только из одного поля - `Symbol`. Также он имеет перегруженные методы хеша и сравнения, где равными считаются модули с одинаковым `Symbol`.

```
public class Module : IEquatable<Module>
{
    public readonly char Symbol;

    public Module(char symbol)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
    }

    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if <paramref name="obj"/> is <see cref="Module"/> and modules are equal</returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Module);

    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if modules symbols are equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(Module module)
    {
        if (module is null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, module))
            return true;

        if (GetType() != module.GetType())
            return false;

        return module.Symbol == Symbol;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Module module1, Module module2)
    {
        if (module1 is null)
        {
            if (module2 is null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        return module1.Equals(module2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Module module1, Module module2) => !(module1 == module2);

    public override int GetHashCode() => Symbol.GetHashCode();
}
```

Есть несколько наследников этого класса. Один из них - `ParametricModule<T>`. Он содержит в себе дополнительно параметр, и равенство двух таких модулей определяется, логично, по равенству `Symbol` и `Parameter`:

```
public class ParametricModule<T> : Module, ICloneable, IEquatable<ParametricModule<T>>
{
    public readonly T Parameter;

    public ParametricModule(char symbol, T parameter) : base(symbol)
    {
        Parameter = parameter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));
    }

    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if <paramref name="obj"/> is <see cref="Module"/> and modules are equal</returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as ParametricModule<T>);

    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if modules symbols and parameters are equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(ParametricModule<T> module)
    {
        if (module is null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, module))
            return true;

        return module.Parameter.Equals(Parameter) && base.Equals(module);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ParametricModule<T> module1, ParametricModule<T> module2)
    {
        if (module1 is null)
        {
            if (module2 is null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        return module1.Equals(module2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ParametricModule<T> module1, ParametricModule<T> module2) => !(module1 == module2);

    public override int GetHashCode() => (Symbol, Parameter).GetHashCode();
}
```

**ПРОБЛЕМА**

Проблема состоит в том, что мне необходимо создать и передавать некоторый шаблон модуля. Шаблоны должны равнятся, если типы классов и `Symbol`-ы модулей совподают. Я хочу получить такой функционал:

```
var moduleA  = new Module('A');
var moduleA0 = new ParametricModule<int>('A', 0);
var moduleA1 = new ParametricModule<int>('A', 1);

moduleA != moduleA0 && moduleA != moduleA1 // РЕАЛИЗОВАНО: разные типы НЕ РАВНЫ
moduleA.Template != moduleA0.Template && moduleA.Template != moduleA1.Template // ХОЧЕТСЯ: шаблоны разных типов НЕ РАВНЫ

moduleA0 != moduleA1 // РЕАЛИЗОВАНО: одинаковые типы с одинаковой буквой, но с разными параметрами НЕ РАВНЫ
moduleA0.Template == moduleA1.Template // ХОЧЕТСЯ: шаблоны одинаковых типы с одинаковой буквой РАВНЫ
```

**ВОПРОС**

Как лучше всего реализовать подобный шаблон, его хранение и получение?

Моё виденье шаблона модуля очень похоже на то же, что если бы все наследники класса `Module` можно было привести к `Module` и использовать его родную функцию сравнения и получения хеша.

Comment: А какого типа Template? Что он должен уметь делать?

Comment: Вы же знаете, да, что весь ваш код можно свернуть в 2 строчки? `record Module(char Symbol); record ParametricModule<T>(char Symbol, T Parameter) : Module(Symbol);` https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoATgUwMYD2WAJgAQCyBxArgDY4AUeAFhFqQMoCeYwBtASgDcmXIRKkACmwhgcAFyxQ8lGvQA8AFQB8TVu269+AGlKapMufJxYBpEBSp1GhvoKFA==

Answer (score 1):

Создаём класс шаблона (GetHashCode нужно дописать):

```
public class Template : IEquatable<Template>
{
    private readonly Type Type;
    private readonly Module Module;

    public Template(Type type, Module module)
    {
        Type = type;
        Module = module;
    }

    public bool Equals(Template other)
    {
        if (this.Type != other.Type)
            return false;

        return this.Module.Equals(other.Module);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is not Template other)
            return false;

        return this.Equals(other);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Template template1, Template template2)
    {
        if (template1 is null)
        {
            if (template2 is null) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        return template1.Equals(template2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Template template1, Template template2)
        => !(template1 == template2);
}
```

Используем его в классах модулей:

```
public class Module : IEquatable<Module>
{
    public virtual Template Template { get; }
    ...
    public Module(char symbol)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
        Template = new Template(typeof(Module), this);
    }
    ...

}
```

```
public class ParametricModule<T> : Module, IEquatable<ParametricModule<T>>
{
    public override Template Template { get; }
    ...
    public ParametricModule(char symbol, T parameter) : base(symbol)
    {
        Parameter = parameter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));
        Template = new Template(typeof(T), this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Вроде, работает как надо.

---

Как вариант, можно сделать класс шаблона вложенным в класс модуля. Это частично скроет его из видимости сторонних разработчиков.

Comment: я думал о таком варианте решения, но получается незначительная проблема в том, что можно как тип передать что угодно и получить только ошибку времени исполнения

Comment: @KuzCode - Тип чего?

Comment: класс `Template` допускает во время компиляции передачу в конструктор любого типа, который может не являтся наследником `Module`

Comment: @KuzCode - И что? Он используется внутри классов-модулей. Там он создаётся автоматически с нужными типами.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, и кстати спасибо за ваш вариант, но темнемение, если перепутать тип в конструкторе класса `Module` об этом будет очень трудно узнать

Comment: @KuzCode - я вас не понимаю. Что значит "перепутать тип в конструкторе"? Вот код уже написан и проверен. Всё, далее просто используем модули - типы шаблонов создаются внутри автоматически с правильными типами.

Comment: @KuzCode - когда мы пишем `var moduleA = new Module('A');`, `var moduleA0 = new ParametricModule<int>('A', 0);` - здесь не нужно указывать типы шаблонов.

Comment: Да, но новые модули тоже нужно писать. Если в одном из новых модулей я напишу в конструкторе, например, вот так `Template = new Template(typeof(int), this);` то компилятор не возмутится, что я передал в шаблон тип `int` вместо наследника `Module`

Comment: @KuzCode - ну, это да.

Comment: Из-за этого даже вы случайно допустили ошибку в коде, написав `new Template(typeof(T), this);` вместо `new Template(this.GetType()), this);`

Comment: @KuzCode - нет, я предполагал, что следует передавать тип `int` (`typeof(T)`), а не тип `ParametricModule<int>`.

Comment: а что бы  вы тогда делали, если бы было 2 параметра или больше?

Comment: @KuzCode - я бы полез бить морду тому, кто ставит нечёткое ТЗ.

Comment: @KuzCode - Если параметров может быть несколько, тогда действительно лучше использовать `this.GetType()`. | Проверку правильности создания всех классов-наследников Модуля можно написать в юнит-тесте. Находим всех наследников, создаём экземпляры, проверяем свойство `Template` - оно не должно быть `null` и оно должно содержать правильный тип.

Comment: @KuzCode - более того, можно написать статический анализатор кода, который прямо в процессе написания кода будет выдавать предупреждения (или ошибки, по вкусу) о неправильной инициализации шаблона. Но это отдельная тема.